# RangeError on codewars prime gap implementation

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, primes

So i have a finished code for the gap primes problem on codewars , but when i execute it i get the error: 
Sometimes the positive results are more than on the previous check , so i'm not sure how to solve it , maybe it's a problem with the optimization but i'm sure it's pretty fast that way

`RangeError: Invalid array length
    at primeSieve
    at gap
    at /home/codewarrior/index.js:113:32
    at begin
    at Object.it
    at /home/codewarrior/index.js:112:14
    at /runner/frameworks/javascript/cw-2.js:152:11
    at Promise._execute
    at Promise._resolveFromExecutor
    at new Promise
    at Object.describe
    at /home/codewarrior/index.js:60:6
    at /home/codewarrior/index.js:125:5
    at Object.handleError`

Here is my code:

```
function gap(g, m, n) {
let arr = [];
let arr2 = [];
function primeSieve(n){
var a = Array(n = n/2),
   t = (Math.sqrt(4+8*n)-2)/4,
   u = 0,
   r = [];
for(var i = 1; i < (n-1)/3; i++) a[1+3*i] = true;
for(var i = 2; i <= t; i++){
 u = (n-i)/(1+2*i);
 if (i%3-1) for(var j = i; j < u; j++) a[i + j + 2*i*j] = true;
}
for(var i = 0; i< n; i++) !a[i] && r.push(i*2+1);
return r;
}
arr2 = primeSieve(n);
arr = arr2.filter(num=>(num >= m) && (num <= n));
for(let i = 0;i<=arr.length;i++){
  let nextValue = i+1;
    if(arr[nextValue] - arr[i] === g){
     return [arr[i],arr[nextValue]]
    } 
}

return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = Array(n = n/2)
```

If `n` is odd, you are creating an array with a non-integer length, which explains `RangeError: Invalid array length`

This can be solved by using parseInt, which will round the float down to the nearest integer.

```
var a = Array(n = parseInt(n/2))
```

Comment: `Math.floor()` would be more appropriate. [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) converts the input to a string and then parses an integer from the string. [`Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) just takes a number directly.